# Writing prepared mysql queries with node mysql?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am new to node.js I don't know whether this is a correct way to write prepared statements in node.js I am using this package https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql I know there are lots of question in stackoverflow covering this but no one suggested this way my colleague suggesting me to do this now I am doubting him..

```
     let query = "INSERT INTO ??(??, ??, ??, ??) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
                let inserts = [`user_active`, `UID`, `rep`, `point`, `status`, `${UID}`, rep, `${point}`, status];

                query = mysql.format(query, inserts);

console.log(query) //Spits out the query
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use ES6 templet string to form the query.
You are already using ES6 templet string in insert statement you can use that to form entire string

```
let query = ‘INSERT INTO user_active(UID, rep, point, status) VALUES(${UID}, ${rep}, ${point}, ${status})’;
```

Not able to get perfect syntax for ES6 templet string as I am answering from mobile, google proper syntax for ES6 templet string. Only thing wrong in my syntax is opening and closing quotes for string.

Comment: No,I think You got the question in the wrong way I am trying to write Safest Mysql Query that could not be penetrated by sql injection.